# What causes that the outer electrons of iron have the same spin and creates a dipool?

Tags: electromagnetism

Iron has the capability of magnetism. The cause of that is that the spins of electrons in the outer shell are the same so they pushes each other away because of Pauli exclusion principle so they are more or less going in interaction with other inner electrons and the atom is getting a north and south pole.

But what is the cause that electrons from fe iron are having the same spin and how is a dipool created by electrons who pushes each other away (isn't that happening all over the atom)?

Comment: See for example [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/manganese-has-more-unpaired-electrons-than-iron-so-why-is-iron-ferromagnetic-man). The situation is more complicated than you describe. At the moment it's hard to answer your question because you misrepresent why ferromagnetism happens.

Comment: See also [Is the ferromagnetism of iron understood completely?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119939/is-the-ferromagnetism-of-iron-understood-completely)